# Why won't the text in this span underline on hover?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the span to underline the text on hover over anywhere in the image, but it won't work. I can change the color on the hover, but not the text decoration. Is it possible to make it underlined? My HTML and CSS are as follows:

```css
.main__story a {
  color: white;
}

.main__story a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}

.main__story span {
   display:block;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 40px;
}

#main__story__img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.main__story {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.myfilter{
  position: relative;
}

.myfilter:after{
  position: absolute; content: ''; display: block; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(245, 245, 245, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54) 100%);
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.contain {
  margin-left: 135px;
  margin-right: 135px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="contain">
      <div class="col-6 main__story">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <div class="myfilter">
            <img
              id="main__story__img"
              class="img-fluid" 
              src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/handsome-guy-and-an-attractive-girl-kiss-each-other-near-a-large-picture-id997518432"
            />
          </div>
          <span id="main__story__span">This is the story of a ...</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

A long-time user, but a first-time poster, as the issue doesn't make sense to me, that I can change some attributes, but not others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting and changing styles of `a` tag in your `:hover`. You need to select the child `span` inside `a:hover` as follows:

```css
.main__story a:hover span{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```css
.main__story a {
  color: white;
}

.main__story a:hover span{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}


.main__story span {
   display:block;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 40px;
}

#main__story__img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.main__story {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.myfilter{
  position: relative;
}

.myfilter:after{
  position: absolute; content: ''; display: block; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(245, 245, 245, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54) 100%);
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.contain {
  margin-left: 135px;
  margin-right: 135px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="contain">
      <div class="col-6 main__story">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <div class="myfilter">
            <img
              id="main__story__img"
              class="img-fluid" 
              src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/handsome-guy-and-an-attractive-girl-kiss-each-other-near-a-large-picture-id997518432"
            />
          </div>
          <span id="main__story__span">This is the story of a ...</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```